# elegant way of convert a numpy array containing datetime.timedelta into seconds in python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, loops, datetime, numpy

I have a numpy array called `dt`. Each element is of type `datetime.timedelta`. For example:

```
>>>dt[0]
datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 36000)
```

how can I convert `dt` into the array `dt_sec` which contains only seconds without looping? my  current solution (which works, but I don't like it) is:

```
dt_sec = zeros((len(dt),1))
for i in range(0,len(dt),1):
    dt_sec[i] = dt[i].total_seconds()
```

I tried to use `dt.total_seconds()` but of course it didn't work. any idea on how to avoid this loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

helper = np.vectorize(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
dt_sec = helper(dt)
```

Comment: Why not use `x.seconds` in the `lambda`? Also, if the array is a flat 1-D array, is `map(lambda x: x.total_seconds(), dt)` faster?

Comment: sure and true (would have to convert list to array in the end).

Comment: I did not know about vectorize...what a useful function! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`numpy` has its own `datetime` and `timedelta` formats. Just use them ;).

Set-up for example:

```
import datetime
import numpy

times = numpy.array([datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 36000)])
```

Code:

```
times.astype("timedelta64[ms]").astype(int) / 1000
#>>> array([ 1.036])
```

Since people don't seem to realise that this is the best solution, here are some timings of a `timedelta64` array vs a `datetime.datetime` array:

```
SETUP="
import datetime
import numpy

times = numpy.array([datetime.timedelta(0, 1, 36000)] * 100000)
numpy_times = times.astype('timedelta64[ms]')
"

python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "numpy_times.astype(int) / 1000"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "numpy.vectorize(lambda x: x.total_seconds())(times)"
python -m timeit -s "$SETUP" "[delta.total_seconds() for delta in times]"
```

Results:

```
100 loops, best of 3: 4.54 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 99.5 msec per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 67.1 msec per loop
```

The initial translation will take about two times as much time as the vectorized expression, but each operation from then-on into perpetuity on that `timedelta` array will be about 20 times faster.

---

If you're never going to use those `timedelta`s again, consider asking yourself why you ever made the deltas (as opposed to `timedelta64`s) in the first place, and then use the `numpy.vectorize` expression. It's less native but for some reason it's faster.

Comment: It should be noted that the conversion is almost trivial using `dt.astype(np.timedelta64) /1000000` (as the native output is microseconds)

Answer (score 1):

A convenient and elegant way is using a `pandas.Series` and using the `dt.total_seconds` attribute:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create example datetime arrays
arr1 = np.array(['2007-07-13', '2006-01-13', '2010-08-13'], dtype='datetime64')
arr2 = np.array(['2007-07-15', '2006-01-18', '2010-08-22'], dtype='datetime64')

# timedelta array
td = arr2 - arr1

# get total seconds
pd.Series(td).dt.total_seconds()
```

```
0    172800.0
1    432000.0
2    777600.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: some links to go with this answer:

`Series.dt`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html

`Series.dt.total_seconds`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html

Answer (score 0):

I like the use of `np.vectorize` as suggested by [prgao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039167/1062948). If you just want a Python list, you can also do the following:

```
dt_sec = map(datetime.timedelta.total_seconds, dt)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Recommendation**

It is recommended to convert as follows:

```py
deltatime.astype("timedelta64[ms]").astype("int64")/1000
```

**Problem of `times.astype("timedelta64[ms]").astype(int)`**

The data type `timedelta64`  stores data as a 64-bit integer.  The `astyp(int)` method will convert data into a 32-bit integer.  So there is a chance that the conversion will fail, as demonstrated below:

```py
date_rng = np.arange(
    np.datetime64("2022-09-01"),
    np.datetime64("2022-09-30"),
    np.timedelta64(1, "D")
)
deltatime = date_rng - np.datetime64("2022-01-01")

print( deltatime.astype("timedelta64[ms]").astype(int) / 1000 )
# output:
#[-479636.48 -393236.48 -306836.48 -220436.48 -134036.48  -47636.48
#   38763.52  125163.52  211563.52  297963.52  384363.52  470763.52
#  557163.52  643563.52  729963.52  816363.52  902763.52  989163.52
# 1075563.52 1161963.52 1248363.52 1334763.52 1421163.52 1507563.52
# 1593963.52 1680363.52 1766763.52 1853163.52 1939563.52]

print( deltatime.astype("timedelta64[ms]").astype("int64")/1000 )
#[20995200. 21081600. 21168000. 21254400. 21340800. 21427200. 21513600.
# 21600000. 21686400. 21772800. 21859200. 21945600. 22032000. 22118400.
# 22204800. 22291200. 22377600. 22464000. 22550400. 22636800. 22723200.
# 22809600. 22896000. 22982400. 23068800. 23155200. 23241600. 23328000.
# 23414400.]
```

Answer (score -3):

You could use a "list comprehension":

```
dt_sec = [delta.total_seconds() for delta in dt]
```

Behind the scenes, numpy ought to translate that to a pretty speedy operation.

Comment: `numpy` isn't doing anything behind the scenes in that. Heck, it'll probably be slower than a loop over a normal `list`.